# Scala: How to get class of mixin composition?

Tags: scala

```
scala> import java.util.Properties
import java.util.Properties

scala> trait Foo extends Properties
defined trait Foo

scala> classOf[Foo]
res0: java.lang.Class[Foo] = interface Foo

scala> class FooP extends Foo
defined class FooP

scala> classOf[FooP]
res1: java.lang.Class[FooP] = class FooP

scala> classOf[Properties with Foo]
<console>:7: error: class type required but java.util.Properties with Foo found
       classOf[Properties with Foo]
               ^

scala> new Properties with Foo
res2: java.util.Properties with Foo = {}

scala> res2.getClass
res3: java.lang.Class[_] = class $anon$1
```

Is there a way of getting class of 'Properties with Foo' without creating an instance or new class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`classOf[X]` only works if `X` corresponds to a physical class. `T with U` is a compound type, and doesn't correspond to a class.

You can use Manifests to determine the erasure of a type. The type erasure of `T with U` is `T`.

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> trait U
defined trait U

scala> manifest[T with U]
res10: Manifest[T with U] = T with U

scala> manifest[T with U].erasure
res11: java.lang.Class[_] = interface T
```

Here you can see that `List[Int]` and `List[_]` have the same erasure:

```
scala> classOf[List[_]]
res13: java.lang.Class[List[_]] = class scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> classOf[List[Int]]
res14: java.lang.Class[List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> classOf[List[Int]] == classOf[List[_]]
res15: Boolean = true
```

Comment: but (new T with U).getClass does return a class. What is it then?

Comment: `new T with U` declares and instantiates an anonymous class that implements the interfaces `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible because "X with Y" is an anonymous definition in your example. This is not the case for "class X extends Z with Y" of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a class literal but you can test if an object meets that type in two different ways:

```
trait X
trait Y

val xy: AnyRef = new X with Y
val zz: AnyRef = new Object with X

xy.isInstanceOf[X with Y] // true
zz.isInstanceOf[X with Y] // false

xy match { case a: X with Y => true; case _ => false} // true
zz match { case a: X with Y => false; case _ => false} // false
```

It's a lot like this generic declaration in java

```
public <T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable> T id(T t) { return t; }
```

That method gets erased to

```
public Comparable id(Comparable t) { return t; }
```

However in Java you cannot say `xy instanceof (X&Y)` but it's really the same as `xy instanceof X && xy instanceof Y`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the composite class, but what you can do is get the list of interfaces implemented and the superclass of a given anonymous class which might suffice.  For example:

```
trait X
trait Y
class Foo
val bar = new Foo with X with Y
val barClass = bar.getClass // class $anon$1
barClass.getInterfaces // Array(interface X, interface Y)
barClass.getSuperclass // class Foo
```

Comment: What I wanted is to get the composition class without creating an instance or new class